# arduino +odroid (linaru ubuntu with eclipse and opencv) + usb camera

Tags: eclipse, serial-port, arduino, odroid

I hope you can help me. I am trying to build a robot but I am kind of stuck. The Arduino Mega is controlling the stepper motors drivers of the robot. The odroid-x is a single board computer that has installed linaro ubuntu and eclipse c++. All the programming is done in C++ and OpenCV is an image processing library.

The odroid-x has only as input a color camera. Therefore, the information from the camera is received and is processed in eclipse. Then, according to the information that is received, the odroid-x should send different integers to the arduino. The arduino should have a program already uploaded in itself, so it will be waiting for an integer and that integer is going to determine what the arduino is going to send to the drivers.

My questions are the following:

1. How can I do a serial communication between the arduino and the odroid-x?
2. How can I send information from eclipse to the arduino with a serial connection?

Thanks so much for any guide you can give me

Answer (score 0):

First, be very, very, very careful.  The ODROID boards use 1.8V signalling, so hooking up your 3.3V or 5V Arduino to the pins that expect no more than 1.8V will give you a burnt ODROID-X.  It is possible to hook these two boards together if you put a level converter between them, and Sparkfun and Adafruit have some of those converters available.  There is even a 1.8V reference voltage pin available... one of the pins that go to the LCD panel RGB-to-LVDS converter board puts out a constant 1.8V.

You could use either the four pins of the little white connector, or UART1, as a serial port, or you can use some of the pins in the 50-pin GPIO block as UART4.  There are board schematics available on Hardkernel's website.  These two UARTs show up as /dev/ttySAC0 (UART1) and /dev/ttySAC3 (UART4).

I don't know how to talk to those UARTs from a program, personally, but I know there are serial communications libraries available for python from watching threads pop up on the ODROID forums.

Comment: Could I use something like this to connect arduino directly to odroid? or would I need to convert the voltage as well? http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G134111883934